# How to remove a set of first 3 characters in an input field, after user is done typing - with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way I can remove a match of a set of first 3 characters in an input field, once a user is done typing, with jQuery?

Comment: Can you provide some code or atleast an example?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove first three characters after user has moved his cursor to other field, use this code...

```
$('#yourInputField').blur(function(event) {
    field = event.target;
    value = field.value;
    $('#yourInputField').val(value.substring(3,value.length));
});
```

Comment: The jquery is looks like this